# Google map load on subviews in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have implement google map in IOS . But the problem is I can not implement google map on my custom view (subview) . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subview and Define the subview class under `GMSMapView`

[image]

```
- (void)LoadMap {

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;

// this line add subView
[self.view addSubview : mapView_ ];  }
```